# Can graph algorithms take nodes' and relationships' properties in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm

I'm starting to use Graph Algorithms plugin of Neo4J (3.3.x) and wanted to ask if the plugin can take in the properties of the nodes/relationships, so that I could add in a request like this:

```
CALL algo.pageRank.stream('Page', 'LINKS', {iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85})
YIELD node, score
RETURN node,score order by score desc limit 20
```

Some properties of the Nodes labeled `Page` (e.g. only the ones with timestamp > certain_date) or only the `LINKS` which have a specific property x.

Or then if it's not possible, shall I use Cypher projection and simply make a Cypher query inside the pageRank algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Cypher projection](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_cypher_projection) to be more selective about which nodes and relationships to process with an graph algorithm.

For example, to execute the [algo.pageRank](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_page_rank) algorithm only on `Page` nodes whose `timestamp > 1000`, and `LINKS` relationships that have a specific property `x`, this should work:

```
MERGE (dummy:Dummy)
WITH dummy, ID(dummy) AS dummy_id
CALL algo.pageRank.stream(
  'OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Page) WHERE p.timestamp > 1000 RETURN CASE WHEN p IS NOT NULL THEN ID(p) ELSE ' + dummy_id + ' END AS id',
  'OPTIONAL MATCH (p1:Page)-[link:LINKS]->(p2:Page) WHERE EXISTS(link.x) WITH CASE WHEN link IS NOT NULL THEN [ID(p1), ID(p2)] ELSE [' + dummy_id + ',' + dummy_id + '] END AS res RETURN res[0] AS source, res[1] as target',
  {graph:'cypher', iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85})
YIELD node, score
WITH dummy, node, score
WHERE node <> dummy
RETURN node, score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 20;
```

NOTE: The graph algorithms are currently badly behaved (i.e., they throw exceptions) when either of the Cypher statements used in a Cypher projection return no results. The above query works around that by making sure that both statements return a dummy node instead of returning nothing. The Cypher statement that "wraps" the algorithm call will then filter out the dummy node if it is returned by the algorithm.